# Access blob in incognito

Tags: file, google-chrome-extension, incognito-mode

When using incognito mode, an extension I use (SingleFile) causes an error when trying to save a link it makes available, which has the format:

```
blob:chrome-extension%3A//xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy
```

The error is `Failed - No file`.

What should I change in the manifest file, in order to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure but would [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito) help?